# Using ProjectItems.item

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

When working with NuGet, I'm attempting to use a powershell script to change a file to an embedded resource.  I'm using a small powershell script recommended on the forums [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/227696). However, my script only works when the file isn't in a folder.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Folder\ReleaseNotes.txt")
$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3
```

How can I adjust this line to find a file even if it is in a folder:

```
$item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("ReleaseNotes.txt")
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, I found it.

ProjectItems is a comprehensive list that contains both files and folders.  In order to access folder/ReleaseNotes.txt you have to go down the nav tree.  This is the solution

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("Folder").ProjectItems.Item("ReleaseNotes.txt")
$item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = [int]3
```